# Where could I find Ubuntu driver for SafeNet IDPrime MD Smart Card

Tags: drivers, smartcard

As I understand my smart card reader (Omnikey 3x21) is supported out of the box by most Linux distribution (Ubuntu included). However, I don't know how could I find a driver for the smart card (Gemalto / SafeNet IDPrime MD Smart Card).

According to
https://superuser.com/questions/1386130/linux-how-can-i-display-and-import-the-certificates-delivered-by-smart-card-re
it is also required to have smart card driver, it is not enough to have only card reader driver.

---

Running `pcsc_scan` gives me no results / no certificates / no smart cards are visible for this util. Although card reader is visible and it is also listed under `lsusb`

---

On Windows it is installed by the system automatically:

[image: Windows driver for smart card]

And it seems that (as mentioned on the thread https://superuser.com/questions/1386130/linux-how-can-i-display-and-import-the-certificates-delivered-by-smart-card-re) - there is separate driver for smart card reader and smart card itself:

[image: smartCardDriver]

Comment: It shouldn't need any driver. It may need some software that according to this https://smartjac.tjanst.on-rev.com/enterprise-security/smart-cards/gemalto-idprime/sac-safenet-authentication-client-desktop-software-for-pki-based-authentication-management is also compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: According to the following thread: https://superuser.com/questions/1386130/linux-how-can-i-display-and-import-the-certificates-delivered-by-smart-card-re "You also need a driver for the smart card itself. It usually comes in the form of a PKCS#11 module, such as libccpkip11.so for CryptoTech or opensc-pkcs11.so for the generic OpenSC-based driver, and is needed because some smartcards have a different internal structure for storing the data"   I've also noticed that when I want to list certificates using `pcsc_scan`, no results / no smart card is visible.